# How to use XMPP over BOSH

Tags: xmpp

So im a little confused about what excatly BOSH is. Is it a way to interact with the XMPP server using http? For example openfire uses BOSH at http://domain.com:7070/http-bind/

How do i use this URL ? What needs to be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074021/open-source-xmpp-library-with-bosh-support

Comment: I am new with XMPP , can anyone please give me the example(link) , to which I follow and understand the XMPP practically. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In simple terms, BOSH is simulating a persistent connection between client and XMPP server using HTTP calls.

The client makes an HTTP(s) request to the server, if the server does not have anything to send to the client, the server holds on to the connection for a configured amount of time (say 30 seconds). After 30 seconds, the server returns the HTTP request initiated by the client. Instantly the client makes another HTTP request and this goes on.

Using this approach, the client simulates a persistent session.

Answer (score 10):

BOSH is defined by [XEP-206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html).