# BOSH XMPP iPhone library

Tags: iphone

Is there a XMPP library for iPhone development with BOSH support? I checkout xmppframework but that does not seem to have bosh support.

Comment: may be this question can help you --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393774/how-to-use-xmpp-over-bosh

Comment: Did you find a XMPP library with BOSH support for iOS/Mac? Found this library, haven't tried it myself. https://github.com/doitian/ocbosh Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this: https://github.com/directi/xmppframework/

Comment: I posted that link for a reason. Here is the link _again_ (since you didn't bother checking other branches): https://github.com/directi/xmppframework/tree/88892827886121404256092cee9813ab3f330645/

Comment: Just to clear my doubts, is XMPPFramework stable? I ask this because the commit history shows the last commit was made 2 years back. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please also check this: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

I don't see that this project was forked from : https://github.com/directi/xmppframework/ though