# Open source XMPP library with BOSH support

Tags: c#, xmpp

Is there any open source XMPP library (written in c#) with BOSH support? I checkout AgsXMPP. AgsXMPP doesn't seem to have bosh support. But Matrix supports bosh. Matrix is a commercial one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [SoapBox SDK Studio](http://www.coversant.com/Product/Studio-Overview.aspx), which offers full support for BOSH (XEP-124) and partial support for XMPP over BOSH (XEP-206).

If this does not work for you, you can also check out the [XMPP Library List](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) and see if any of the other C# libraries fit your needs.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Norman. SoapBox SDK Studio seems to be bit complex. Anyway, I have downloaded latest version of [AgsXMPP](http://http://www.ag-software.de/downloads/index.php?dir=agsxmpp%2FNet2%2F&download=agsXMPP.dll). It supports BOSH.

Comment: They are no longer open source according to Michael Holdmann 
Executive Vice President of Coversant, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

We can bind the bosh (using AgsXMPP library) as follows,

```
        XmppClientConnection xmpp;
        xmpp = new XmppClientConnection();
        xmpp.Port = 5280;
        xmpp.Server = jidSender.Server;
        xmpp.SocketConnectionType = agsXMPP.net.SocketConnectionType.Bosh;
        xmpp.ConnectServer = "http://localhost:5280/http-bind";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Jabber net on google code. This ia open source and does support BOSH.
http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/